# Print statements in resultset.next() loop not printing

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm working on a database assignment and I've run into a problem. 
We are required to print out 3 rows at a time, stopping at each multiple of 3 rows and prompting the user to continue or to break.

This is using Java JDBC with an Oracle Database.

```
if (rset.next()){
    // At this point, there are reviews to show                                                                                                          
    int rinc = 0;
    String seenextreviews = "y";
    System.out.println("Rating - Text - Reviewer - RDate");
    while(rset.next()){
        // Iterate through the result set                                                                                                                
        System.out.println("Increment: " + rinc);
        if(rinc % 3 == 0) {
            // Displayed 3 reviews                                                                                                                       
            seenextreviews = "maybe";
            while(!seenextreviews.equals("y") && !seenextreviews.equals("n")){
                seenextreviews = console.readLine("See next reviews (y/n)? ");
                if (!seenextreviews.equals("y") && !seenextreviews.equals("n")){
                    System.out.println("Invalid input '" + seenextreviews + "'");
                }
            }
            if (seenextreviews.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Breaking...");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Continue...");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rset.getInt("rating") + " - " + 
            rset.getString("text") + " - " + 
            rset.getString("reviewer") + " - " + 
            rset.getString("rdate"));
        rinc = rinc + 1;
    }
}
```

For the given code, all of the 'System.out.println(values)' within 'if (rset.next())' only `System.out.println("Invalid input '" + seenextreviews + "'");` and `System.out.println(rset.getInt("rating")...);` prints, while everything else doesn't print.

However, console.readLine("text") still prints text before asking user input.

Why are my print statements not printing? Is the only alternative to change the query to select 3 rows at a time, and calling multiple queries?

Answer (score 2):

> For the given code, all of the 'System.out.println(values)' within 'if (rset.next())' only

From [`ResultSet#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position.

So, it looks like your query returns a single row and you read it in the `if (rset.next())` condition, when going to the `while(rset.next())` you're reading from the 2nd row to the end, but since you don't have a 2nd row to read, the `while-loop` ends.

Possible solution: use a flag to print the title:

```
int rinc = 0;
String seenextreviews = "y";
while(rset.next()) {
    //this serves as flag
    if (rinc == 0) {
        System.out.println("Rating - Text - Reviewer - RDate");
    }
    //rest of your code logic...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed like this:

```
int rinc = 0;
boolean firstTime = true;
String seenextreviews = "y";

while (rs.next())
{
    if(firstTime)
    {
        System.out.println("Rating - Text - Reviewer - RDate");
        firstTime = false;
    }
    System.out.println(rset.getInt("rating") + " - " + 
            rset.getString("text") + " - " + 
            rset.getString("reviewer") + " - " + 
            rset.getString("rdate"));
    rinc += 1;

    if (rinc == 3)
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        while (true)
        {
            String seenextreviews = console.readLine("See next reviews (y/n)? ");
            if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(seenextreviews.trim()))
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            else if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(seenextreviews.trim()))
            {
                rinc = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input . Try again");
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you're printing the title even if there are no results.